# Downscaling images: what determines the speed vs. quality trade-off?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-scaling

> TL;DR?
>
> When scaling an image and optimizing for speed and quality, is the target image size more or less important than the scaling ratio?

I'm working on an image server that will scale images to various sizes.  We're using the [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) library and it has a speed vs. quality tradeoff option.  These settings choose between nearest neighbor, bilinear, and bicubic interpolation methods.

There's also an "automatic" option that determines the best speed vs. quality tradeoff.  According to the documentation:

> Used to indicate that the scaling implementation should do everything
> it can to create as nice of a result as possible. This approach is
> most important for smaller pictures (800px or smaller) and less
> important for larger pictures as the difference between this method
> and the SPEED method become less and less noticeable as the
> source-image size increases. Using the AUTOMATIC method will
> automatically prefer the QUALITY method when scaling an image down
> below 800px in size.

Looking at the implementation of the [determineScalingMethod](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib/4.2/org/imgscalr/Scalr.java#Scalr.determineScalingMethod%28int%2Cint%2Cfloat%29) method, it appears the optimal speed vs. quality decision is made based on the largest dimension of the image at the target scale.

It's counterintuitive to me that the best quality to speed tradeoff is determined by the target image size as opposed to the scaling ratio.  Does anyone know what other libraries do when making the same trade-off decision or have first hand experience with optimizing speed and quality when selecting interpolation algorithms?

Comment: I don't know imgscalr in detail, but I agree that it sounds strange that anything but scaling ratio should matter... The Java2D interpolation methods does not do a good job when scaling down more than 1/2 in any dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It's the total size (in bytes) of the output image. They try to minimize the file size while maintaining the general quality; the smaller the file size the faster the transmission to the client. The algorithm you linked to is [documented](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib/4.2/org/imgscalr/Scalr.java#Scalr.0THRESHOLD_QUALITY_BALANCED), I suggest you review what they have to say (excerpted here) -

> The bigger the image is being scaled to, the less noticeable
>   degradations in the  image becomes and the faster algorithms can be
>   selected.
>
> The value of this threshold (800) was chosen after visual, by-hand,
>   A/B testing  between different types of images scaled with this
>   library; both photographs and  screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Elliott.  Sorry if I failed to imply that I've perused the documentation and source.  The part I don't follow is that the implementation seems to imply that scaling from 400 to 300 square pixels would produce more noticeable artifacts than scaling from 3200 to 800 square pixels.  That's the part that's counterintuitive.  The documentation also mentions that the importance of quality is based on the source size, but they select quality by destination size.  That seems a little contradictory as well.  I suppose I'll do my own visual A/B testing to see the results.

Comment: I think it's saying you're unlikely to notice lower quality settings with larger image dimensions. That is a 3200x3200 image at 75% quality probably looks better then the same image scaled to 800x800 at 95% quality.